# Debugging C++ solution from C# solution

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll

I have two VS solutions. Solution `A_sol` is C++/C# projects. Solution `B_sol` has project `B_proj` that is C# wrapper around C++ `*.dll` generated by `B_proj` project in `A_sol`. 
How do I debug `A_proj` from `B_proj` ?
UPDATE: one of the projects in `B_sol` is an executable.

Comment: Once the code is already running it doesn't really matter if it's exe or library code - it's all the same ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do I debug A_proj from B_proj ?

If I understood you correctly, A_proj is a C++ project. Below I will give my advice based on this assumption.

Note that it doesn't really matter from which project/solution you start debugging as long as you have the debug info (in other words, for C++ projects - if Visual Studio is able to pick up PDB's).

So you may either run your executable from the solution, or, as suggested by @hoodaticus [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45201268/5722863), attach to the process which is already running. Whether your project is executable or not, you will be able to attach to it as long as:

1. DLL is loaded into that process
2. You have the PDB file that matches the DLL (generated during the build)

So I'll just repeat the same advice

> In the other project, do Debug > Attach to Process > pick your process
>   from the list.

but I'll add that you have to pay attention to select "Debug these code types -> Native" for the process that contains your C++ dll. This part is often missed and confuses people, taking some time to discover (personally, I often get into it) [image]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run the process you want to debug outside the debugger.
2. In the other project, do Debug > Attach to Process > pick your process from the list.

Comment: Problem is that `A_sol`(one that generates C++ .dll) is not an executable solution. it is purely a library solution.

Comment: @newprint - if your library isn't used in any executables then there is no need for you to debug it, so that's a self-solving problem.  If it is used in an executable, then you can run that executable and debug it from your library solution using Attach to Process just as I said.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to debug by pressing F5 (rather than having to pick your process each time),

- Right-click the startup project (the EXE) and choose Properties
- In the Debug tab, select Enable native code debugging

The above steps are from this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-managed-and-native-code?view=vs-2019